# Delete duplicate with same ID PHP/PDO/MYSQL

Tags: mysql, php, duplication

I'm new to databases and I need your help I'm working on a website and I have few problems. I'm using PDO.
There is a user table, with unique ID, name and password. User enters his username and password and is put to the next page where he enters time, date and a third parameter. Those 3 parameters are put into anoter database with user's ID (ID is set with PHP's session). This table has no primary key, since user can insert multiple entries.
Sounds great, but... I want to delete duplicates, or even better prevent user to insert a duplicate.
I tried with this:

```
$alter = "ALTER IGNORE TABLE data ADD UNIQUE INDEX (ring_time, ring_date, bell_mode)";
$query = $db->prepare($alter);
$query->execute();

try {                           
    $insert_s = "INSERT INTO data(id, ring_time, ring_date, bell_mode) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $query = $db->prepare($insert_s);

    $query->execute(array($_SESSION['id'], $_POST['ring_time'], $_POST['ring_date'], $_POST['mode']));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "<p class='already_entered'>Already entered.</p>"
}
```

This works somehow right, but if different user inserts same values, it catches the error, even though his ID is different. I'm pretty sure that $alter statement is wrong.
The other thing is: I want to delete every entry which date (the table's date entry is 'date' type) is past today's day. I tried with:

```
DELETE FROM data WHERE CURDATE() > ring_date";
```

but with no success, it deletes stuff, but not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like just the session id would be 'unique' for defining the User?  And maybe a separate table would hold the multiple `bell_mode` values for each user?  *You* have to think through the application to figure out what is "unique"; we cannot do it for you.

`CURDATE()` is a *date*, not a *datetime*.  `NOW()` is a *datetime*.

```
CURDATE() < ring_date -- before midnight this morning
```

It is clumsy to have two separate columns for a "date" and a "time".  I strongly suggest you combine those two columns into a `DATETIME` datatype; I'll call it `ring_dt`.  `DATE(ring_dt)` and `TIME(ring_dt)` are the 'date' and 'time' parts of `ring_dt`.  It's easier to take a `DATETIME` apart than to put it together.

```
CURDATE() < ring_dt -- same as above
ring_dt > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY  -- more than 24 hours ago (to the second)
ring_dt > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY  -- before yesterday's 12am. (not very useful)
```

`- INTERVAL 1 DAY` and `- INTERVAL 24 HOUR` have the same effect.